# Translate decimal number to weeks and days?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How would I translate a decimal into a number of weeks and days?

For instance, take this number: `12.4893617021277`

`12` is the number of months. Then `.4893617021277` would be weeks and days.

So I'd want the output to be something like: `12 months, 1 week and 6 days`.

For clarification, I'm not looking for *exact* numbers here. I'm making the assumption that there are 4 weeks in a month and 7 days in a week.

```
original = 12.4893617021277
4 weeks × .489361702127658 = 1.9574468085 weeks # That gives me 1 full week, with the remainder going in to the number of days
7 days in a week × .9574468085 = 6.7021276595 days
```

Final translation = `12 months, 1 week and 6 days`

I'm running Ruby 2.1.2 and running Rails 4 (in case there are some random helpers I'm not aware of).

Comment: Some bit of arithmetic might help.  Hint: 1 year = 12 months = 365 days (unless a leap year).  Moreover, 1 week = 7 days.

Comment: The number of days within a month differs for different years (as well as for months), so you cannot calculate that without knowing what year it is.

Comment: @sawa I'm not trying to translate a specific date here. Just rough estimates. For example, for "0.5 of 1 month" I'd translate to "2 weeks" based on the assumption that there are 4 weeks in a month. I should probably update the post to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution, pretty clear.

```
def integer_and_decimal_part(float)
    integer = float.to_i
    decimal = float - float.to_i
    [integer, decimal]
end

def calculate(float)
    months, months_decimal = integer_and_decimal_part(float)
    weeks, weeks_decimal = integer_and_decimal_part(4*(months_decimal))
    days = (7*weeks_decimal).to_i

    {months: months, weeks: weeks, days: days}
end

calculate(12.4893617021277)

=> {:months=>12, :weeks=>1, :days=>6}
```

Comment: Small tweak...how about adding a `years` option? So if months is > 12, then year = 1 (and then it caries on down to the necessary months/weeks/days)?

Comment: OK. Before returning the hash, do years = months/12 and years = months % 12.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not getting 12 mos, 1 week & 6 days - 30 * .4893617 is coming out to 14.6 days so that would be 2 weeks, right?  My solution isn't the prettiest but it works.

```
def num_to_date(val)
  results = {}
  results[:month] = val.to_i
  remain = val % val.to_i
  days = remain * 30 #30 days in a month
  if days > 7
    results[:weeks] = days.to_i / 7
    rem = days % days.to_i
    rem < 0 ? results[:days] = 0 : results[:days] = rem.to_i
  else
    results[:weeks] = 0
    results[:days] = days
  end
  results
end

num = 12.4893617021277
puts num_to_date(num)
```

output:

```
{:month=>12, :weeks=>2, :days=>0}
```